# grails g:set with null values in gsp page

Tags: pdf, grails, set, gsp

In my grails project I am using PDF plugin. For this purpose, I use the following link to generate a PDF:

```
<g:pdfLink class="pdf" pdfController="patient" pdfAction="privacyPolicy" pdfId="${patientInstance?.id}" ><g:message code="patient.generatePrivacy" /></g:pdfLink>
```

the `privacyPolicy()` method is as follows:

```
def privacyPolicy(Long id){

    def patientInstance = Patient.get(id)

    if (!patientInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'patient.label', default: 'Patient'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    if(patientInstance.cf.equals("")) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'cf.not.present.message', args: [message(code: 'patient.label', default: 'Patient'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    [patientInstance: patientInstance]

}
```

the gsp page has got two variables defined as follows:

```
<g:set var="birthdate" value="${PatientController.getDateFromFiscalCode(patientInstance?.cf)}" />
<g:set var="cityName" value="${PatientController.getBirthplaceFromFiscalCode(patientInstance?.cf)}"/>
```

both variables are dependent by `cf`, that could be not present for a `patientInstance`

Analyzing the flow in debug mode(when cf is empty), I've noticed that `privacyPolicy()` is called twice. First time it enters into second if, but then it enters in first if.

The error in console is the following:

```
ERROR pdf.PdfService  - org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRRuntimeException: Can't load the XML resource (using TRaX transformer). org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; 

there was a problem with PDF generation java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'length' on null object
```

I think that depends on gsp variables, but I don't know how to manage when they are empty or null (in this case they are equals to "")

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Instead defining `birthdate` & `cityName` in gsps by calling controller method, just pass them as a model values.

Like in your controller:

```
def privacyPolicy(Long id){

    def patientInstance = Patient.get(id)

    if (!patientInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'patient.label', default: 'Patient'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    if(patientInstance.cf.equals("")) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'cf.not.present.message', args: [message(code: 'patient.label', default: 'Patient'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    [patientInstance: patientInstance, birthdate: getDateFromFiscalCode(patientInstance.cf),
            cityName: getBirthplaceFromFiscalCode(patientInstance.cf)]

}
```

Using the controller in the way you used in gsp may work but is not up to the mark.

Comment: the second if gives me some problem...infact it works only if I comment it...if I use it I have the same exception above, and the message code shown is related to firs if (default.not.found.message)

Comment: I want that if cf is empty, user can see another error message (cf.not.present.message). So, why do that check gives an error?

Comment: Yeah, you should be getting `NullPointerException` (NPE). Since your `cf` can be null or empty, then accessing `equals` method on the same may fail. So for this simply replace that if condition with: `if (!patientInstance.cf) {}`. Since in groovy, null values/empty-strings/0/false/empty-lists are treated as false condition. So this will work.

Comment: I've modified the code as you have suggested, but the NullPointerException still stands

Comment: Can you please tell me exact line where NPE is being thrown. As I can't see your logs for the line numbers. That must be throwing at your one of the method i.e. **getBirthplaceFromFiscalCode** or from **getDateFromFiscalCode**.

Comment: The 'length' is used inside the PDF plugin that allows me to use the g:pdflink tag. You can see that source [here](https://github.com/aeischeid/grails-pdfplugin/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/pdf/PdfController.groovy)

Comment: Have you tested this url manually in your browser: http://localhost:8080/patient/privacyPolicy/<id>? Since we need to make sure that there must be some response from this url. Otherwise **b** will be null in the pdf controller.